# Autosizing Text Marks in Vega

Tags: kibana, vega

I'm currently developing my own Metrics in Vega. [Here is an example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub0Mg.png)

I am just using text marks, here is the [source code for a very similar example](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/text.vg.json) to mine. In the example height and width are specified. However, I'm looking for the text to be autosized - that is, height and width are determined from the space the marks take up. The usual global setting to do this would be, `autosize: pad` or `autosize: fit` but these don't seem to correctly fit text marks on their own.

I'm reaching out to anyone who knows how to do this. Since I am using these in a Kibana dashboard, the autofitting would allow us to scale these metrics to any size we'd like, independent of any amount of text.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have since solved this and will post the answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question,

I defined a 100x100 grid using scales and axes in Vega. And then plotted my words to fit inside this grid - since you can specify the x,y positions of the words.

After this the autofit applied correctly. I made sure to scale the fontsize (which is height of text in pixels) to the height of the panel (external signal).

Finally I had to hide the axes. So inside the axes I added this `labels: false, domain: false`. With a few extra additions this was my result. This is totally resizable within Kibana.

[image]